# Applescript for changing filenames

Tags: automation, applescript, filenames, rename, finder

I would like to change thousand of filenames with an applescript.

The filenames are all made in this way:

firstPart - secondPart XX.xxx

with the XX a certain number and the .xxx either a jpg or a png extension.

I would like to simply change the parts around so that it would become:

secondPart - firstPart XX.xxx

I have come up with this but my codings skills fail me.

```
tell application "Finder" to set aList to every file in folder "ImageRename"
set text item delimiters to {" - ", "."}
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in aList
    set aFile to (item i of aList)
    try
        set fileName to name of aFile
        set firstPart to text item 1 of fileName
        set secondPart to text item 2 of fileName
        set thirdPart to text item 3 of fileName
        set newName to secondPart & " - " & firstPart & "." & thirdPart
        set name of aFile to newName
    end try
end repeat
```

This works only the number sticks to the second part.
So it becomes:

SecondPart XX - firstPart.xxx

How can I make two integers as a text item delimiter?

Please help me out and teach me along the way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the space as the delimiter and build the parts.
Edited: to allow for spaces in the text parts.

```
tell application "Finder" to set aList to every file in folder "ImageRename"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in aList
    set aFile to (item i of aList)
    try
        set fileName to name of aFile
        set lastParts to text item -1 of fileName
        set wordParts to (text items 1 thru -2 of fileName) as string
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " - "
        set newName to {text item 2 of wordParts, "-", text item 1 of wordParts, lastParts}
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
        set name of aFile to (newName as string)
    end try
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
```

Comment: Hehe, yeah I tried this... Results that in some parts of the name are spaces as well...

Comment: So just use the space as a delimiter to separate the XX.xxx from the previous, then use the " - " to break up the two parts and switch them.  Piece of cake.

Comment: I edited to code to demonstrate. No need to use grep to do this if you want vanilla AS.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I wanted to try, to add delimiters in the loop itself. Thanks! It works :-) Both crunchy GREP and Vanilla AS are pleasant tastes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question how to use an integer as an text item delimiters is just:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
```

You can set multiple text item delimiters at once but the problem is that when using multiple text item delimiters you have actually no idea what was between the two text items. Also the order of how the delimiters appear in the text is not important when using text item delimiters. Therefore I would suggest using regular expressions instead, you define a certain format instead of separating a string and guessing which character was actually the separator.

```
tell application "Finder" to set aList to every file in folder "ImageRename"
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in aList
   set aFile to item i of aList
   set fileName to name of aFile as string
   set newName to do shell script "perl -pe 's/^(.*) - (.*) ([0-9]{2}\\.(jpeg|png))$/\\2 - \\1 \\3/i' <<<" & quoted form of fileName
   if newName is not fileName then set name of aFile to newName
end repeat
```

The reason I use `perl` and not `sed` is because `perl` does support the I flag in the substitution which makes the comparison of the expression case insensitive.

**edit** (requested explanation):
The format of the old string is something like: String can start with any character (^.*) up to the literal string " - " ( - ) then followed by any character (.*) again. The string have to end with a string starting with space and 2 digits ( [0-9]{2}), followed by a literal period (\.) and end with either jpeg or png ((jpeg|png)$). If we put this all together we get a regex like "^.* - .* [0-9]{2}\.(jpeg|png)$". but we want to group the match in different sections and return them in a different order as our new string. Therefore we group the regular expression into 3 different sub matches by placing parentheses:

```
^(.*) - (.*) ([0-9]{2}\.(jpeg|png))$
```

The first group will match the firstPart, the second group will match secondPart and the third group (XX.xxx) will match the remaining part. The only thing we need to do is reorder them when we return the new string. A backslash followed by a number in the new string will be replaced by the matching group. In the substitution command this will be notated as /s/search/\2 - \1 \3/flags.

The last part of our substitution are some flags, I place `I` as a flag for case insensitive matching.

Putting this all together gets me

```
s/^(.*) - (.*) ([0-9]{2}\.(jpeg|png))$/\2 - \1 \3/I
```

*note: because \ is in applescript a special character we have to write a \ down as \\*

Comment: I'll hope it (self) explains better why I chose a regular expression over using text item delimiters in this situation.

Comment: In fact Applescript's text comparisons and handlers are case insensitive by default. Otherwise you have to turn the case sensitivity on by wrapping your code using `on considering case ... end considering`

Comment: @ShooTerKo: The command is executed in Bash and not in AppleScript. That means the case consideration of AppleScript has nothing to do with string comparisons done inside command line utilities.

Comment: @djbazziewazzie: Yes, sorry. I've read false (too fast) and thought you use Perl instead of Applescript because of case sensitivity. Sorry again!

Comment: Cool! I understand it better now.Does shell scriptnig has a lot of common with GREP? I recognise quite some similarities...

Pardon my curiosity, could you also explain these parts:

perl -pe 's/ ... i' <<< or if that's too much to ask; where can I start learning more about shell scripting? Or is it Perl?

Comment: Although I really like the code it gives an error code saying that it can't be transformed in Unicode text...

Comment: My mistake @Mauritz. I have corrected the code. I thought that a `aFile` was already an unicode string. The passed argument was clearly not.

Comment: try again, it seems that something went wrong while editing yesterday.

Comment: Cool! It works... I changed (jpeg|png) to ([a-z]{3}) but I would like to include jpegs as well... of course I could write jpeg|jpg|png but... How would you write ([a-z]{[2-4]})? So both .ai and .jpeg would be included ;-)

Comment: Almost correct :)... It Should be `[a-z]{2,4}` without parentheses. The whole expression should be `^(.*) - (.*) ([0-9]{2}\.[a-z]{2,4})$`